# SDK Manager doesn't see new version of build-tools

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

SDK Manager doesn't see the new version of build-tools, although the new version exists. So, my Android Studio requires to install build-tools 23.0.2:

[image]

But when I open SDK Manager, I don't see this version:

[image]

And I can't find build-tools 23.0.2 even using command line:

[image]

I tried to force https sources to be fetched using http or clear cache of SDK Manager, but nothing changed. By the way, I installed this version of build-tools this morning on another computer. Please give me advice how to update the window of SDK Manager?

Comment: Try the command line approach (http://tools.android.com/recent/updatingsdkfromcommand-line), might be an Android Studio/SDK Manager issue.

Comment: @Egor, I updated my question with command line output.

Comment: I think you first need to update SDK tools to the latest, it might be showing build tools compatible with your current sdk tools

Comment: Does this belong to superuser? (it's about programming environment but not programming em si)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select Obsolete check box, as shown below

[image: Select Obsolete check box]

Comment: I did this, but the version 23.0.2 of build-tools didn't shown anyway.

Comment: Before installing build tools 23.0.2 you need to upgrade android sdk to the latest version (24.4.1 atm).
Forcing sdk to update is possible with this PR #87

To make sure if this is your case you can quickly check by appliyng fork with this PR included like this:

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.plastiv:sdk-manager-plugin:b04aea1cddf87e78db9a4372794d678f9e568c48'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'

sdkManager {
    minSdkToolsVersion '24.4.1'
}

Comment: thank you, your answer was very helpful. The reason of my fail was that my build tools weren't compatible with my sdk tools.

Comment: glad to help you out

Answer (score 0):

What say your build.gradle ?

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

Comment: Yes, it's exactly so.